# How to represent an empty IntSet in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

As the title asks, how would I represent an empty IntSet?

For example, I know that an empty list is represented as `[]`. I know that IntSet has type `[(Int, Int)]`, and I was wondering what an empty IntSet would look like. I suppose it's not `[()]`, nor `[(,)]`.

Thanks!

Comment: Or if, as it appears, you're actually using lists of pairs rather than "actual" `IntSet`s, then of course an empty intset is simply represented by the empty list, `[]`.

Comment: `IntSet` has not *per se* type `[(Int, Int)]`. Exactly what is the semantics of this representation?

Comment: Do you mean an `IntSet` from [`Data.IntSet`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.6.2.1/docs/Data-IntSet.html) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have defined

```
type IntSet = [(Int, Int)]
```

as implied in the question (but why? what is the other `Int` for?), then the empty list *is* an empty `IntSet`:

```
empty :: IntSet
empty = []
```

Indeed, the empty list is an empty list of any type, including of the type `[(Int, Int)]`.